# Can I get the past owner of a metaplex NFT without digging through this NFT's transactions?

Tags: metaplex, nft, jsonrpc-api

I need to get the owner of a NFT at a certain date.

I could just dig through this NFT's transaction history, but it seems a bit cumbersome.

Is there another way?

Comment: There is no field containing previous owners that one could just read. Unfortunately your proposed approach - going through the transactions is the only one that works given the abilities solana provides. There might exist indexers which save the data and make it easier accessable like solscan is showing, though.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers, not comments. "No, because ..." is also a solution!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other way. Digging through the transaction history is the way to go.

You can automate that by creating a bit of JS/TS code, of course.

When the history is long and/or you have a lot of NFTs to track, you can easily run into rate limits with the standard RPC endpoints, so it might be a good idea to get a private RPC node from vendors like QuickNode or GenesysGo. Some have free tiers as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. Previous account state is not stored anywhere today on a validator nor RPC node.

The only way that you can figure out an owner of an NFT at time x is taking current state and replaying backwards all transactions until time x.